# Regex / parse with php

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I get html with `CURL` in PHP and I receive html page.

In this page I can see this line :

```
genereadresse('name','domain','com');
```

I want to parse with regex to get just return `name@domain.com`

I don't have an idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*?\('([^']*)','([^']*)','([^']*)'\);.*$
```

You can try this.Replace by `$1@$2.$3` or `\1@\2.\3`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uC8uO6/5

```
$re = "/^.*?\\('([^']*)','([^']*)','([^']*)'\\);.*$/";
$str = "genereadresse('name','domain','com');";
$subst = "$1@$2.$3";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: I have other content in the html imagine : blablalalalalalgenereadresse('name','domain','com');blablablalalala